# Creating dynamic struct arrays using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I have a problem regarding creating dynamic struct arrays. The thing is I read from a file and I am not allowed to initialize the struct after the `scanf`. The thing is that I want to create x amounts of structs of the type vinnareinfo. I can add that we are only allowed to use C90 since it's a school project. Would really apreciate all the help out there! :D

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct vinnareinfo{
    char fornamn[20];
    char efternamn[20];
    int ar;
    };

main(){


struct vinnareinfo *vinnare;

int i = 0, x;
FILE *file;

file = fopen("C:\\Uppgifter.txt", "r");
if (file != NULL){
    fscanf(file, "%d", &i);
}
else{
    printf("Ange antal vinnare:");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    i = i - 1;



    for (x = 0; x < i; x++){
        printf("Ange år: ");
            scanf("%d", ??? )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really consider `förnamn` and `år` as valid identifiers in C90? I hope you don't...

Comment: **Please** don't use non-English characters. Please.

Comment: You should stick to only ASCII characters when writing the code.

Comment: Sorry, forgott about it! Using native language since it's easier for me to relate :)

Comment: @arshajii: No, god no. Rather, the OP should stick to the basic execution character set.

Comment: does it need to be in an array or can you use another data structure? if yes you could create a linked list for instance, every time you read a record, malloc a struct instance and add it to the list.

Comment: otherwise check out `realloc`, it can expand a heap block to become larger once you malloced it. that way you do not need to know how many records are going to be read but instead can dynamically expand the array as the user enters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make things easier and more readable consider defining a new data type for your structure:

```
    typedef struct {
    char fornamn[20];
    char efternamn[20];
    int ar;
    }vinnareinfo;
```

You can find more useful info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

```
scanf("%d", &i);
vinnareinfo *v = (vinnareinfo*)malloc((i-1)*sizeof(vinnareinfo)); //allocated an array of i elements of type  vinnareinfo
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...

printf("Ange antal vinnare:");
scanf("%d", &i);
//i = i - 1;//remove

vinnare = malloc(i * sizeof(struct vinnareinfo));//check return value of malloc

for (x = 0; x < i; x++){
    printf("Ange ar: ");
    scanf("%d", &vinnare[i].ar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (fscanf(file, "%d", &i) != 1) {
    perror("fscanf");
    exit(1);
}

vinnare = malloc(sizeof(struct vinnareinfo) * i);
if (!vinnare) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
}

for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    int rc = fscanf(file, "%*s%*s%d",
        sizeof(vinnare->fornamn)-1,   &vinnare->fornamn,
        sizeof(vinnare->efternamn)-1, &vinnare->efternamn,
        &vinnare->ar);
    vinnare++;
    if (rc <= 0) {
        perror("fscanf");
        break;
    }
}
```

N.B. May be need to replace '*' in fscanf formatting string by '19', and remove 'sizeof(vinnare->...)-1' args. That works for printf, but should be tested for scanf!

Comment: `*` of scanf is not width op.